# How to apply style to all UIViews programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a class that defines all styles on a UIVIew.
They are all predefined but I'm not sure when to fire this.

When I try to create an extension for this:

```
extension UIView
{
    func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?)
    {
        self.stylize() // Another extension somewhere (not here my problem)
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Method 'willMoveToSuperview' with Objective-C  selector conflicts with
>   previews declaration with the same Objective-c selector

I have tried to override it, but didn't worked either.

Any ideas on how to be able to apply a same behaviour when all of my UIViews will become visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swizzling technic to customize UIView's function. Take a look at:

- http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ (objective-c)

or

- http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/  (swift)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at [StyleSheet](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet) (a styling micro-framework with composable and reusable styles) for implementation example, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Swift's `Extensions` are similar to `Categories` from Objective-C, what you are trying to do is not allowed in Swift.

You cannot `override` existing functionality:

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

Source: [Swift Extensions - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Depending on what it is that you are trying to style, you might want to take a look at `UIAppearance`, it will allow you to style default colors for the `UINavigationBar`, amongst other things. NSHipster has a good post about it: [NSHipster - UIAppearance](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/)

Comment: It's not that simple, I'm trying to register styles and give names of the elements, to support nested styles for example. I needed to be able to catch the willMoveToSuperview event and fire it. It does not need to be an extension. I just don't know when it will became visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `UIView` with the method `.stylize()`.
Then each view you create, you inherit of you `UIView` subclass.

You'll be able to cal `.stylize()` on each UIViewSubclass. Simply write the style code inside the subclass and inherite.

Or

Use a category to add the method to the existing `UIView` class.

See : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: That forces me to inherit from it every time I need to use it, some of my classes are only on storyboard.

Comment: I gave you 2 solutions. 
And the fact is that you always inherit from a class. NSObject, UIView, UIViewCOntroller, etc. 
You simply have to inherit your views form MyStylizedView than UIView

Comment: If I create this only on storyboard I don't need to create a class for that, it's managed by xcode, I don't need to explicitly create a class for that. This approach would force me to (for every UIView having a class) just to be able to apply styles.

Comment: No you don't understand the solution. You're not forced to do it on every view you have. Only on the view you want to style with code. And it works perfectly with storyboard dude.

Comment: I was trying to avoid mixing Objetive-C but probably there is no other way of catching this event.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of swizzling (not generally recommended), or subclassing as noted by David in his answer, there isn't really a way to override *existing* methods on a class and its subclasses.

One thing you might try is creating a base class for your view controller instead of all your views.  In your view controller base class, you could override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to recurse through the view hierarchy and call `stylize` on each view. This means you would be using the subclass approach in fewer places (just view controllers as opposed to all views).

Another thing you might consider if taking the subclassing approach with UIView is that if you are subclassing anyway, you can take advantage of things like @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable to better integrate those UIView subclasses with storyboards and live preview.

I wrote a Swift library which does exactly this, and it works well for the type of styling it seems you want to do:  https://github.com/daniel-hall/Stylish